# Use part of an interface to create an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this **interface**:

```
export interface Config {
  buttons: {
    close?: boolean;
    accept?: boolean;
  }
  ...
}
```

When I import the aforementioned interface into another module and do this I get an error:

```
buttons: Config.buttons = {};
```

> "Config" only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace her

I'm using `buttons` variable later in the code:

```
 onConfig = (config: Config) => {
   Object.assign(this.buttons, config.buttons);
 }
```

Any advice on how to make it work?

It works fine, when I do:

```
buttons: any = {};
```

But is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought `typeof` might work here, but it doesn't. To solve this, you could move buttons into its own interface:

```
export interface Buttons { // or ButtonsConfig or whatever
  close?: boolean;
  accept?: boolean;
}

export interface Config {
  buttons: Buttons;
  ...
}
```

Then use it as a type on a property like so:

```
buttons: Buttons = {};
```

Comment: a little follow up question. Names like `Buttons` and `Config` are not descriptive, it's imposible to say if it's interface or not, how would you indicate in a name that it's an interface. What's common practice? Maybe `ButtonsInterface` or something like that...

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov I know what you mean. The answer to that is mostly personal preference and opinion. Looking at some of my typescript code, I would personally write `ConfigStructure` and `ButtonsConfigStructure` (I like verbosity). For me the word `Interface` or doing `IConfig` makes me think of something that needs to be implemented by a class. I think `Config` is fine, but yeah by the name it could be confused for something that needs to be instantiated.